# Find file on filesystem using php that partially matches a user id

Tags: php, function, filesystems, find

The current issue I'm facing is this.

I have a directory as such webroot:banners/users/

The directory contains user images named as such:

```
136-20111115001231.jpg
(where "136" equals a users ID and the remaining numbers are a timestamp)
```

So for instance if we had these stored in our directory:

```
136-20111115001231.jpg
255-20100228153178.jpg
10-20111003124511.jpg
320-20090130145800.jpg
```

Is there a way of easily searching for a file in our directory (using PHP) that begins with a specified user id?

For instance, if we wanted to find the user image for **$userid *(136 for instance)*** could we do something the equivalent of:

```
    <?php
    $filename = filefind("banners/users/$userid*.jpg");
    ?>
```

Which would search for jpegs starting with "136" and return the filename (in this case - 136-20111115001231.jpg).

I had a look at some PHP filesystem references but I'm sure I keep overlooking the function that would do this.

Any help you could give would be brilliant!

My guess is that this is an easy one :)

Cheers, Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

Comment: So I was! Thank you very much, but with a name like glob() no wonder I missed it! :)